# How to avoid app restart after pressed home button in android phone

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am implementing an android app with Xamarin.

I performed the following step.

1. Start the APP
2. The APP opened with first page "A"
3. Pressed a button and go to page "B"
4. Pressed home button on mobile phone.
5. Click on the APP icon to go back to the APP.
6. The app looks like restart and opened in page "A"

Why would this happened? How could I avoid this.

I have checked my android manifest file.

There is no "android:launchMode" item.

Comment: please post more info, what is considered to be a page in your app? how is the transition beeing made?

Comment: This issue will occur when setting the **LaunchMode** to **SingleTask**. Please check the **LaunchMode** of the MainActivity, you could get that at the `Activity` tag above the Activity class.

Comment: Is this Forms based? (i.e. you are using the term "Page", do you mean "Activity"). If strictly Xamarin.Android, what is the Activity lifecycle (OnRestart or OnCreate) when you relaunch the app?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and in my code, "NoHistory" was set true in MainActivity.cs. So I changed it to false:

```
    namespace [YourAppName].Droid
    {
        [Activity(..., MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = false, ...]
        public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
        {
...
```

My app literally resumes when I select the app after pressing a home button.
I'm wondering if your case is the same as mine.